# Web book reader pagination algorithm

Tags: javascript, web-applications

The problem:
Web application online e-book reader (like amazon kindle cloud reader).
How to calculate (estimate) number of pages depending on current viewport size (and other parameters like formation options: font-style,size etc..)?

Have anyone worked on such algorithm to perform this operation in browser?

Any Ideas how amazon/google or other e-book readers do this?

Thanks in advance for any good ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at Readium, a Chrome add-on which does all these things.